# What does undefined method `configure' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rvm

What does undefined method `configure' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) mean?

I tried reinstalling and reinstalling.  I'm also have trouble updating the GEMFILE to ruby 2.4.2. Your Ruby version is 2.4.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.5. I tried "bundle update" removing 2.2.5 but it gives me a error... I tried everything. and now I get this nil:Nil:Class error... PLease help!

The last known error I did was to remove the .ds-store and i typed something add gitignore or something because I was having trouble with the git pull. I found this while I was troubleshooting and I also hit git commit - m " ".

This was when the nil:Nil:Class error popped up each type i try to run the rails s.

```
/Users/sandychow/roughhouse-web/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sandychow/roughhouse-web/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/sandychow/roughhouse-web/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/sandychow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sandychow/roughhouse-web/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /Users/sandychow/roughhouse-web/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Sandys-MBP:roughhouse-web sandychow$
```

Comment: Can you share your `application.rb` and to specify what Rails version you're using?

Comment: Which OS are you in, Debian? That Gemfile error means you need a different version of Ruby to run your app. `bundle exec update` does not remove Ruby versions, its just updates the current gems to the latest available versions. But did you try to delete something from the RVM folder?

Comment: Using RVM means different versions of Ruby you can manage easily with, `rvm use 2.2.5`, for any app before running ruby commands.

Answer (score 0):

What Ruby version manager are you using, i would suggest you to use rvm to maintain ruby manager and with rvm use ruby~2.2.5 as it is mentioned in your gem file. first go to project directory and change your ruby version to 2.2.5 and then run bundle update. this may resolve your issue. [RVM](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/install_language_runtime.html)